# Multi part rar archive error checking

Tags: rar

So I have a rar split up into multiple pieces and one of them is bad. I can redownload the parts and suspect an error in transmission of the files to be the source of error. Is there any way I can narrow down which part is bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than hash checking each file, not really.  Not that I know of.

You could begin extracting and then it should error out on the bad file.

Comment: I'm using 7zip and it just has a problem with the entire data set. I'll give winrar a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

try extracting them with [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/). it stops at the broken part and an informational diagnostics window pops up, telling you which part(s) is/are corrupted.

Comment: I assumed he was using winrar.  I shouldn't assume =\

Comment: Many archive apps can open .rar extension. I had a similar problem once and I was using 7z. It was extracting the content just fine with no problems at all but I was getting an error while opening the file. So I tried winrar and sure one part was corrupted, downloaded it again and everything worked fine. I thought may be the OP is having a similar case.

Answer (score 2):

the command line rar utility supports the `r` option.  you can launch this for each part individually and examine the output.  it complains if the file is corrupted. it will also try to repair problems if it finds them.  occasionally there is enough parity data to correct the problem.

Comment: often for large rar archives that are split like this which are of questionable origin, one file is corrupted on purpose so that web crawlers can't determine the content.  sometimes the whole group of rar parts is posted a couple of places with different rar parts being corrupt on each

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unrar` package for extracting and see which part the extraction fails.

```
unrar x TheArchive.part1.rar
```

The result will be something like this:

```
Extracting from TheArchive.part3.rar

...         TheArchive/data                                        43%
TheArchive/data1.cpi    : packed data checksum error in volume TheArchive.part3.rar

Extracting from TheArchive.part4.rar

...         TheArchive/data                                         58%

Extracting from TheArchive.part5.rar

...         TheArchive/data                                         73%
TheArchive/data1.cpi    : packed data checksum error in volume TheArchive.part5.rar
```

By looking at the above output, we findout that part3 and part5 seems to have issues. Perhaps redownloading them will fix the problem.